# How do I find the MAC address behind a router

Tags: networking

I'm reading Head First Networking.On page 198 to 203 this book traces a mole with the source MAC address.However, as far as I know, the router changes the source MAC address of a frame upon forwarding it to a subnet, so what we can get in a frame is just the MAC address of the router.Since a lot of devices are connected to the router,how can I tell which one behind the router is the original source of information?

Comment: A MAC address is only significant or seen on the layer-2 broadcast domain (LAN) where the host with that MAC address is. When a frame crosses a router from one network to another network, the frame with the MAC address is stripped, and the information in the frame, including the MAC addresses in the frame, are lost. The next hop may not use a layer-2 protocol that uses MAC addresses, but if it does, a new frame will be created for that hop. The new LAN doesn't need to know the MAC addresses on the original LAN.

Answer (score 0):

From the source IP address. IPs don't change from hop to hop. The IP is technically inside the frame if you unpack the frame headers.